# Steam получение логина

Tags: php, ulogin

Пользуюсь стимовским API, и мне нужно получить именно логин участника, мне выдает ид, имя и прочую информацию, а как получить логин?...

Пользуюсь сервисом uLogin, пробовал через OpenId - но там тот же метод используется.
**ISteamUser GetPlayerSummaries**

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я могу судить по https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API — такой возможности нет.

Comment: В том то и дело, что сколько не пересмотрел их АПИ, не могу найти логин...
Вот и думал, может есть какие - то иные способы..